# Convert String into array or multidimensional array with specific string as key

Tags: php

I want to convert string into multidimensional array, so that I can display it in unordered list

Contents of $notes variable:

```
Conditions:
  Adult fares apply from 13 years old and above. Child fares apply from 4 to 
  12 years old
  Infants not included

What to bring:
  Sunscreen, water bottle, hat, sunglasses, camera, small 7kg overnight bag 
  if using the hop on hop off option

What to wear:
  Warm clothes, windbreaker, comfortable walking shoes

Insurance: 
  We highly recommend all passengers have travel insurance coverage

Optional extras paid on arrival:
  Helicopter joy flight over the 12 Apostles AUD145

Not included:
  Dinner (at own expen
```

What want an output like this

```
  [
     'conditions => ['some','some'],
     'what to bring' => ['content','content']
     .......
  ]
```

What I tried so far is using explode function

```
   explode(',',$notes)
```

But this is the output which I donot want

```
 array:8 [
    0 => """
       Conditions:\n
       Adults fares ....
       \n
      What to bring
      .....
    1 => "water bottle"
    2 => "hat"
    ......
 ]
```

So expected output as unordered list

```
     conditions
          1. ....
          2.....
     what to bring
           1....
           2....
     Inurance
           1..
           2...
```

notice that keys(conditions, what to bring..) are dynamic names, so it may change from time to time but the format is the the same

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to post the string as text and not image. Post the sample of the desired output also

Comment: I always downvote questions that has pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode the string by `EOL`, loop thru the array and check if the string ends with `:`, if it does, use it as the key.

```
$notes = ''; //Your string here

//Init variables
$final = array();
$tempKey = "";

//Convert the string into an array
$arr = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $notes), 'trim');

//Loop thru the array
foreach($arr as $val) {
    if ( substr(trim($val), -1) === ':' ) $tempKey = rtrim(trim($val),":");
    else $final[ $tempKey ][] = trim($val);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $final );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [Conditions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Adult fares apply from 13 years old and above. Child fares apply from 4 to
            [1] => 12 years old
            [2] => Infants not included
        )

    [What to bring] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sunscreen, water bottle, hat, sunglasses, camera, small 7kg overnight bag
            [1] => if using the hop on hop off option
        )

    [What to wear] => Array
        (
            [0] => Warm clothes, windbreaker, comfortable walking shoes
        )

    [Insurance] => Array
        (
            [0] => We highly recommend all passengers have travel insurance coverage
        )

    [Optional extras paid on arrival] => Array
        (
            [0] => Helicopter joy flight over the 12 Apostles AUD145
        )

    [Not included] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dinner (at own expen
        )

)
```